# Audio pitch seems to have been artificially made higher - without changing speed?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

I have a 3gp video file that I'm working with.  The audio in the file appears to have been artificially made higher - but without changing the speed (i.e. audio and video tracks are still in sync and still at normal speed).  All the sources I can find on the net seem to imply that pitch changes require speed changes, though I could be wrong.

How was this done?

And is there a way I can correct it, using tools like avconv / vlc?  I am working in Linux.  I don't have access to the original, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is possible.

You can use [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) for this, which will run on Windows, Mac and Linux

There is an option to change the pitch with out changing tempo (speed)